# Django media upload not working when uploading image through code

Tags: python, django, media

I have created a Django application in which i have a signup page which asks a user to upload their profile picture.
When I'm uploading the profile picture through the Django admin panel, the images are being uploaded to the correct path and are being displayed in the website. However, the error comes when I directly select the image to upload when signing up and then When I click on the uploaded image in Django admin it shows page not found and the path to the image is being showed as C:\Users\hp\Workspace\findem\media\image.jpg

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'findem/static')
]

# media folder settings
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'media').replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

User Model

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Represents a user profile inside our system"""

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=profile_pic)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/profile_pictures/', default='photos/User.jpg')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    highest_degree_earned = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    graduation_year = models.IntegerField(default=2020, blank=False)
```

Template :

```
   <form class="needs-validation" novalidate autocomplete="off" 
action="{% url 'signup' %}", method="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}
<div id="Personal_Information">
<h5 class="loginSignup">Personal Information</h5>

   <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputprofile" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Profile Picture</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="input-group">
      <div class="custom-file">
       <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" class="custom-file-input" id="inputprofile" name="inputprofile">
       <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputprofile" aria-describedby="inputprofile">Choose file</label>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group required row">
    <label for="inputname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Full Name <span id="required-field">*
     </span>
    </label>

   <div class="col-sm-5">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputname" id="inputname" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" required>
     <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
     <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your full name.</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputemal" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email <span id="required-field">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-sm-5">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter a Valid Email Address" required>
       <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
       <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid email.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password <span id="required-field">*</span></label>
     <div class="col-sm-5">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Choose a Password" required>
       <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
       <div class="invalid-feedback">Please chose a valid password.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3" id="loginButton">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

view :

```
def signup(request):
"""View for Signing-up into the system"""
if request.method == 'POST':

    # Get form value
    profile_picture = request.POST.get('inputprofile')
    name = request.POST.get('inputname')
    email = request.POST['inputEmail']
    password = request.POST['inputPassword']
    highest_degree_earned = request.POST['inputDegree']
    college_name = request.POST['CollegeName']
    graduation_year = request.POST['inputGradYear']
    skill_1 = request.POST['upload_skill1']
    skill_2 = request.POST.get('upload_skill2', '')
    skill_3 = request.POST.get('upload_skill3', '')
    skill_4 = request.POST.get('upload_skill4', '')
    skill_5 = request.POST.get('upload_skill5', '')
    skill_6 = request.POST.get('upload_skill6', '')
    join_date = datetime.now()


    # Check Username
    if UserProfile.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
        messages.error(request, "That Name already taken")
        return redirect('signup')
    # Check email
    else:
        if UserProfile.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, "That email is being used")
            return redirect('signup')
        else:
            # Looks Good
            user = UserProfile.objects.create_user(profile_picture=profile_picture, name=name, email=email, 
            password=password, highest_degree_earned=highest_degree_earned, college_name=college_name, 
            graduation_year=graduation_year, skill_1=skill_1, skill_2=skill_2, skill_3=skill_3, skill_4=skill_4,
            skill_5=skill_5, skill_6=skill_6, join_date=join_date)

            # #Login after register
            # auth.login(request, user)

            user.save()
            messages.success(request, "You are now registered and can log in")
            return redirect('login')

else:    
    return render(request, 'pages/signup.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your form tag to be be like this :

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate autocomplete="off" 
action="{% url 'signup' %}", method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

add request.FILES to profile_picture like that :

```
    profile_picture = request.FILES.get('inputprofile') or None
```

Than in your create request you do that :

```
        else:
        if UserProfile.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, "That email is being used")
            return redirect('signup')
        else:
            # Looks Good

            if profile_picture != None
                user = UserProfile.objects.create_user(profile_picture=profile_picture, name=name, email=email, 
                    password=password, highest_degree_earned=highest_degree_earned, college_name=college_name, 
                    graduation_year=graduation_year, skill_1=skill_1, skill_2=skill_2, skill_3=skill_3, skill_4=skill_4,
                    skill_5=skill_5, skill_6=skill_6, join_date=join_date)
            else:
                user = UserProfile.objects.create_user(name=name, email=email, 
                    password=password, highest_degree_earned=highest_degree_earned, college_name=college_name, 
                    graduation_year=graduation_year, skill_1=skill_1, skill_2=skill_2, skill_3=skill_3, skill_4=skill_4,
                    skill_5=skill_5, skill_6=skill_6, join_date=join_date)
```

For the default picture try to change it to this :

```
 profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/profile_pictures/', default='/media/photos/User.jpg')
```

Comment: I did this earlier and after that nothing is being uploaded.it just shows blank near the profile picture when i view it in the admin area

Comment: Show the view that handle the signup action

Comment: There is another problem with my app. As you can see that I have set a default image for profile picture field but it isn't working. I have the image in my media folder too.

Comment: I have added a new section on the answer, and would you please mark my answer as correct for your question

Comment: i did what you mentioned for default image, but it is just showing blank i.e., nothing is uploaded for profile picture when i don't select one.

Comment: Can you create a test user with the default image and then go to the profile section and see where he is looking for the profile pic

Comment: I just checked, and i'm pointing to the right path for default. what happens when i dont set a profile picture and the get request fetches nothing and maybe it then sets the profile picture to nothing?

Comment: Ok i think that you have a point here i have added or None to the picture get request, i have updated the answer, try it.

Comment: Fid you run the makemigrations after adding the default to the model ?

Comment: Thanks. Although your initial answer did not work. i got an idea from it. i used it and the problem got solved

Comment: glad it helped !

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML form, you need to use.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Without that, the file is not sent to the server.
Add this tag to your form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
</form>
```

and to get the files at django part use `request.FILES.get('filename')` in your view

```
profile_picture = request.FILES.get('inputprofile')
```

Comment: Thanks.My default image for profile pictuer field that i have set isn't working. can you help me with it?